# Blazor Component not updating UI when method is invoked by other component

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have 3 components. When I want is to call the `New()` method of component C from component B.
That works with following code (I get the Console.Writeline). But the UI is not updating. I have tried to set `StateHaseChanged()` in the `New()` method, but that gave me following errors. Many Thanks!

Error

> WASM: System.InvalidOperationException: The render handle is not yet
>   assigned.

ComponentA (SideBar Item)

```
<NavLink href="@href">
    <div @onclick="OnClick.InvokeAsync">@Text</div>
</NavLink>


@code {
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

ComponentB (SideBar)

```
<ComponentA Text="Something" Onclick="@(() => componentC.New())" />


@code {
    ComponentC componentC = new ComponentC();
}
```

ComponentC (Page)

```
@code {
    public void New()
    {
        //Dostuff..
        Console.WriteLine("Testing");
        //StateHasChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your component naming is slightly off. Probably `ComponentB` uses `ComponentC` internally (in the @code block). Is this correct?

Comment: @Artak That was indeed correct, I have changed it in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `ComponentC` in `ComponentB` as follows:

```
<ComponentA Text="Something" Onclick="@(() => componentC.New())" />
<ComponentC @ref="componentC" />

@code {
    private ComponentC componentC;
}
```

The `ComponentBase` class implements the `IComponent.Attach(RenderHandle)` method, which is not being called when you simply new-up the component in the code. However, when you do this in the markup, things are wired up correctly.

Comment: That worked indeed, but that renders Component C on the page. See as Component A = Sidebar Item, Component B = Sidebar, Component C = Page. I have edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

change your code into this:

```html
<NavLink href="@href">
    <div @onclick="Navigate">@Text</div>
</NavLink>


@code {
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
    private void Navigate(){
     OnClick.InvokeAsync();
     }
}
```